# How to find cause of 500 Internal Server Error in IIS server logs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

A user is getting a 500 error, but I'm unable to reproduce it, so I took a look at the logs.

The logs only tell me when and on what path the 500.0 error happened; is there any way to (retroactively) find the line or stack trace of the error?

Comment: It's in the Event Log item.

Comment: You want *Failed Request Tracing* : http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85

Comment: Not from those logs, you have to enable failed request tracing (or use another third party tool)

Comment: log4net for the win!

Comment: There is no `Failed Request Tracing` item under Configure in the Actions pane (for the default web site) like the guide says?

Comment: I didn't have Tracing installed. (Guide: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/tracefailedrequestslogging)